# How to change a task's behavior based on how a user calls it, without requiring them to change code?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm using `sbt-s3` to upload my uberjar artifacts to S3 for deployment. What I need now is for a developer for be able to chose whether they're pushing to staging or production.

`sbt-s3` looks something like this,

```
  mappings in upload <<= (name, version, scalaBinaryVersion) map { (name, version, scalaBinaryVersion) =>
    Seq(new java.io.File("target/scala-%s/%s.jar" format(scalaBinaryVersion, name)) -> ("%s.jar" format name)) }
```

Say I wanted to prefix `%s.jar` with a string like `"staging"` or `"production"` depending on how a user called SBT (it seems silly to have them edit `Build.scala` every time they want to push). For example: `sbt s3Upload` goes to staging and `sbt production:s3Upload` or `sbt production s3Upload` would go to production.

I'm having trouble understanding scopes and how I can use them to solve this problem. I can't just make a setting and hardcore `S3Prefix in Production` because then they can't push to staging. I didn't have any luck making a `production` task that overrides a default of `"staging"` to be `"production"` for following tasks, either.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution might be to use input tasks for that, this is a simple task definition from the the [sbt documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Extending/Input-Tasks.html):

```
  demo := {
  // get the result of parsing
  val args: Seq[String] = spaceDelimited("<arg>").parsed
  // Here, we also use the value of the `scalaVersion` setting
  println("The current Scala version is " + scalaVersion.value)
  println("The arguments to demo were:")
  args foreach println
}
```

Depedending on the argument you can then push to staging or production.

I think there could be a more elegant solution with configurations, but I didn't do that before.